# SQL query to compare the average of two different sql queries with dates

Tags: mysql, date, compare, average

I have a table with name_id, date and col1-col5 with rates.
I'm looking for a solution to compare the average of the rates of the latest day with the average of the rates of the day before the latest day.
When the average of the latest day is higher then the day before the latest day, then 'up'. When lower, then 'down'.

| id | name_id | date | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 28-07-2023 | 4,64 | 4,70 | 4,80 | 4,90 | 5,10 |
| 2 | 3 | 28-07-2023 | 4,75 | 4,86 | 4,87 | 5,05 | 5,15 |
| 3 | 3 | 28-07-2023 | 4,88 | 4,88 | 4,98 | 5,08 | NULL |
| 4 | 4 | 28-07-2023 | 4,98 | 5,04 | 5,16 | 5,29 | 5,45 |
| 5 | 4 | 28-07-2023 | 4,99 | 5,03 | 5,18 | 5,33 | 5,54 |
| 6 | 3 | 29-07-2023 | 5,00 | 5,07 | 5,15 | 5,29 | 5,52 |
| 7 | 3 | 29-07-2023 | 5,09 | NULL | 5,22 | 5,37 | 5,52 |
| 8 | 3 | 29-07-2023 | 5,30 | 5,30 | 5,45 | 5,50 | 5,70 |
| 9 | 4 | 29-07-2023 | 5,32 | 5,47 | 5,62 | 5,67 | 5,82 |
| 10 | 4 | 29-07-2023 | 5,32 | 5,42 | 5,52 | 5,62 | 5,67 |

The latest day:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`) IS NOT NULL THEN 
         (COALESCE(`col1`, 0) + COALESCE(`col2`, 0) + COALESCE(`col3`, 0) + COALESCE(`col4`, 0) + COALESCE(`col5`, 0) ) / 
            (CASE WHEN `col1` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
             CASE WHEN `col2` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col3` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col4` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col5` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       END) AS Average
       FROM table WHERE `date`= (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM table) AND name_id=3;
```

Average: 4.9028

The day before the latest day:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`) IS NOT NULL THEN 
         (COALESCE(`col1`, 0) + COALESCE(`col2`, 0) + COALESCE(`col3`, 0) + COALESCE(`col4`, 0) + COALESCE(`col5`, 0) ) / 
            (CASE WHEN `col1` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
             CASE WHEN `col2` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col3` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col4` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col5` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       END) AS Average
       FROM table WHERE `date` = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table WHERE date < (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table)) AND name_id=3;
```

Average: 5.3200

This query only compares the rates of the latest day with a 'fixxed' rate of 5.00 (not what I need):

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN AVG(CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`) IS NOT NULL THEN 
         (COALESCE(`col1`, 0) + COALESCE(`col2`, 0) + COALESCE(`col3`, 0) + COALESCE(`col4`, 0)+ COALESCE(`col5`, 0) ) / 
            (CASE WHEN `col1` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
             CASE WHEN `col2` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col3` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col4` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col5` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       END) < 5.00 THEN 'up' ELSE 'down' END AS 'Rate'
       FROM table WHERE `date`= (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM table) AND name_id=3;
```

Rate: up

How to make a query to compare the 2 outputs?

Edit:
@user1191247

What is the reason for having 5 values per row instead of all values for the same name_id/date being in the same row?
Besides the mentioned column 'name_id' there is another column 'fixed interest period'.
The table contains mortgage interests and the columns col1-col5 represents different risk classes of mortgages. The interest of the mortgage is depending of the risk class and the interest period.
One row is representing all classes of a particular interest period. One mortgage has multiple periods. The column name_id is representing the mortgage. In my example there is one mortgage with 3 periods with 5 risk classes per day.
So your understanding about a 'set of multiple rows' is correct. You are right about the difference between the the difference between the average of all values, and the average of some intermediate averages.
I need to compare the same set of rows. (my sample data is not correct with 1 colum with NULL last day and 4 columns with NULL the day before)
So when comparing exactly the same sets of rows, the outcome of averages can be different, but the result (up - down) will be the same.
Because your solutions is less code, I'll use it for my project.
I'm still looking for a solution to compare the sets of rows with the latest date when the average was not the same.
As not all rates change daily, I have a lot of 'Equal' as result. I want to know if the average is higher of lower since the latest change of the rates.

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Your current query is calculating the average of averages. Is this your intention, or did you want the average? - https://dbfiddle.uk/0eOaqkhs

Comment: @user1191247
In need the average of one or more rows (depending on date and name_id) from col1-col5.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of my question. There is a difference between the overall average, and the average of intermediate averages, when the intermediates are based on differing numbers of values (due to your NULLs) - https://dbfiddle.uk/SMamQM_M. What is the reason for having 5 values per row instead of all values for the same name_id/date being in the same row? Or, much better still, having each value in its own row, then each value can have its specific datetime, and querying the data becomes much easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that, where there are multiple rows for the same name_id/date pair, the columns col1 - col5 across the multiple rows form a single set. If my understanding is incorrect, you can completely ignore my answer ;-)

This is a contrived example to highlight the importance of understanding the difference between the average of all values, and the average of some intermediate averages (where the number of values in the intermediates varies).

Let's take this modified version of your sample data:

| id | name_id | date | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-07-28 | 4.64 | 4.70 | 4.80 | 4.90 | 5.10 |
| 2 | 3 | 2023-07-28 | 4.75 | 4.86 | 4.87 | 5.05 | 5.15 |
| 3 | 3 | 2023-07-28 | 6.30 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 4 | 3 | 2023-07-29 | 5.00 | 5.07 | 5.15 | 5.29 | 5.52 |
| 5 | 3 | 2023-07-29 | 5.09 | NULL | 5.22 | 5.37 | 5.52 |
| 6 | 3 | 2023-07-29 | 5.30 | 5.30 | 5.45 | 5.50 | 5.70 |

And here is the same data with the sum, value count and average per row added:

| id | name_id | date | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | sum | val_count | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-07-28 | 4.64 | 4.70 | 4.80 | 4.90 | 5.10 | 24.14 | 5 | 4.828000 |
| 2 | 3 | 2023-07-28 | 4.75 | 4.86 | 4.87 | 5.05 | 5.15 | 24.68 | 5 | 4.936000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2023-07-28 | 6.30 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6.30 | 1 | 6.300000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2023-07-29 | 5.00 | 5.07 | 5.15 | 5.29 | 5.52 | 26.03 | 5 | 5.206000 |
| 5 | 3 | 2023-07-29 | 5.09 | NULL | 5.22 | 5.37 | 5.52 | 21.20 | 4 | 5.300000 |
| 6 | 3 | 2023-07-29 | 5.30 | 5.30 | 5.45 | 5.50 | 5.70 | 27.25 | 5 | 5.450000 |

Now let's look at the average of the averages vs the average of all values for each name_id/date grouping:

| name_id | date | avg_avg | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2023-07-28 | 5.3546666667 | 5.010909 |
| 3 | 2023-07-29 | 5.3186666667 | 5.320000 |

The avg_avg value has decreased between 2023-07-28 and 2023-07-28,
but the avg value has increased for the same period.

Modifying [Ankit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76793465/1191247) to compare the averages, instead of the averages of intermediate averages, we end up with:

```
WITH latest_day_avg AS (
    SELECT name_id,
        SUM(IFNULL(col1, 0) + IFNULL(col2, 0) + IFNULL(col3, 0) + IFNULL(col4, 0) + IFNULL(col5, 0))
        /
        SUM((`col1` IS NOT NULL) + (`col2` IS NOT NULL) + (`col3` IS NOT NULL) + (`col4` IS NOT NULL) + (`col5` IS NOT NULL)) AS Average
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE `date` = (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM tbl)
    GROUP BY name_id
),
prev_day_avg AS(
    SELECT name_id,
        SUM(IFNULL(col1, 0) + IFNULL(col2, 0) + IFNULL(col3, 0) + IFNULL(col4, 0) + IFNULL(col5, 0))
        /
        SUM((`col1` IS NOT NULL) + (`col2` IS NOT NULL) + (`col3` IS NOT NULL) + (`col4` IS NOT NULL) + (`col5` IS NOT NULL)) AS Average
    FROM tbl 
    WHERE `date` = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tbl WHERE date < (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tbl))
    GROUP BY name_id
)
SELECT CASE WHEN lda.average < pda.average THEN 'Down'
            WHEN lda.average > pda.average THEN 'Up'
            ELSE 'Equal'
       END AS Rate
  FROM latest_day_avg lda
  JOIN prev_day_avg pda ON lda.name_id = pda.name_id
 WHERE lda.name_id = 3;
```

Here's a [db<fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EqRTSiJu).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I have updated my question cause my answer is too long for a comment.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I need, for sets of rows. I have updated your fiddle [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/MHRBk_GG)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed update in the fiddle. [I have updated](https://dbfiddle.uk/7d5Rcm8r) based on grouping by name_id/date (average of averages). I added the generated column for `col_avg` just to make the queries a bit easier to read, this could be put into a CTE (see last example in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7d5Rcm8r)), instead of adding to tbl.

Comment: AWESOME!
I'm very happy with it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

1 possible way is to calculate the average first, Join and compare the result then -

```
WITH latest_day_avg AS (
SELECT name_id,
    AVG(CASE
            WHEN COALESCE(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`) IS NOT NULL 
                THEN (COALESCE(`col1`, 0) + COALESCE(`col2`, 0) + COALESCE(`col3`, 0) + COALESCE(`col4`, 0) + COALESCE(`col5`, 0) ) / 
                     (CASE WHEN `col1` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
                      CASE WHEN `col2` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
                      CASE WHEN `col3` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
                      CASE WHEN `col4` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
                      CASE WHEN `col5` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                  END) AS Average
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    `date` = (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM table)
GROUP BY name_id
),
prev_day_avg AS(
SELECT name_id,
    AVG(CASE
         WHEN COALESCE(`col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `col4`, `col5`) IS NOT NULL THEN 
         (COALESCE(`col1`, 0) + COALESCE(`col2`, 0) + COALESCE(`col3`, 0) + COALESCE(`col4`, 0) + COALESCE(`col5`, 0) ) / 
            (CASE WHEN `col1` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + 
             CASE WHEN `col2` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col3` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col4` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
             CASE WHEN `col5` IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
       END) AS Average
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    `date` = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table 
              WHERE date < (SELECT MAX(date) FROM table)) 
GROUP BY name_id
)
SELECT CASE WHEN lda.average < pda.average THEN 'Down'
            WHEN lda.average > pda.average THEN 'Up'
            ELSE 'Equal'
       END
  FROM latest_day_avg lda
  JOIN prev_day_avg pda ON lda.name_id = pda.name_id
 WHERE name_id = 3;
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, thanks for your answer. Unfortunally I get : unknown column 'latest_day_avg' in field list

Comment: @Stefan, I have fixed the error now. Please try edited version.

Comment: Thnx, this works. You're the man!